# Get nameID of button that clicked

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am programming for Windows Phone 8.1.
When I click on a button, I Call cmdDeleteBlock_Click.

```
AddHandler cmdDelete(1).Click, AddressOf cmdDeleteBlock_Click
AddHandler cmdDelete(2).Click, AddressOf cmdDeleteBlock_Click
AddHandler cmdDelete(3).Click, AddressOf cmdDeleteBlock_Click
...
```

How can get name of button (ID) that was clicked in cmdDeleteBlock_Click.

```
Private Sub cmdDeleteBlock_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
' Get button name (Id) of button that clicked **here**
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name from the object received in the event handler. Stating an example in c#

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string Name = ((Button)sender).Name;
}
```

Similarly you can get other properties as well.

Comment: I can't. I need 15 reputation. I just start now.